# Why can't Racket find my module export?

Tags: module, racket, lang

I have a very simple module with a single export, in file "m.rkt"

```
#lang racket
(module m racket
  (provide dec)
  (define (dec n)
    (- n 1)))
```

and other module in file "n.rkt" that uses it

```
#lang racket
(module n racket
  (require "m.rkt")
  (define (id x)
    (+ 1 (dec x))))
```

At the REPL, I try to load this second module

```
Welcome to Racket v6.0.1.
> (current-load-relative-directory "h:\\tmp")
> (require "n.rkt")
h:\tmp\n.rkt:8:10: dec: unbound identifier in module
  in: dec
```

It appears to finding the two module expressions just fine, but can't resolve the export of `dec` from "m.rkt".  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Update:  Commenting out the `#lang racket` language-selection syntax in both files causes things to work properly.  According to Section 6.2 of the Racket Guide, the `#lang racket` is shorthand for a module declaration, so my `(module ...)` forms were declaring submodules.  Live and learn...

Comment: You should answer your own question below and accept it...

Answer (score 3):

(copied from update to question)

Commenting out the #lang racket language-selection syntax in both files causes things to work properly. According to Section 6.2 of the Racket Guide, the #lang racket is shorthand for a module declaration, so my (module ...) forms were declaring submodules. Live and learn...